# How does programmatically reading Outlook emails using C# work one day and stop working on a different day?

Tags: c#, automation, outlook

My goal is to automate the reading of outlook emails using my C# script. Last week, it was working as it should with no problems. Since the beginning of this week, I am getting below error:
"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed"
My code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using olook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace ReadingEmails
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static (string[], olook.MailItem[]) ReadMail()
        {
            try
            {
                List<string> bodyList = new List<string>();
                List<olook.MailItem> emailList = new List<olook.MailItem>();

                olook.Application outlookApp = new olook.Application();

                olook.Folder inbox = outlookApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) as olook.Folder;
                olook.Folders childFolders = inbox.Folders;
                foreach (olook.Folder folder in childFolders)
                {
                    //Reason behind this that if we have an outlook rule to automate moving emails into specific
                    //folder it will be less emails than the inbox for the script to navigate through
                    if (folder.Name == "testFolder")
                    {
                        //Retrieving mail items from the folder
                        olook.Items mailItems = folder.Items;
                        foreach (object item in mailItems)
                        {
                            if (item is olook.MailItem)
                            {
                                olook.MailItem mailItem = (olook.MailItem)item;
                                //Will only be looking at emails with subject line: Manual Incoming2
                                //Only looking at unread emails, otherwise we will have infinite loop
                                //of emails being sent
                                if (mailItem != null && mailItem.Subject != null && mailItem.UnRead)
                                {
                                    if (mailItem.Subject.Contains("Incoming"))
                                    {
                                        //will not look at any emails that are replies or fowards. otherwise
                                        //we will have infinite loop of emails being sent
                                        try
                                        {
                                            if (!mailItem.Subject.Contains("RE:") || !mailItem.Subject.Contains("FW:"))
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " : Found Email");
                                                bodyList.Add(mailItem.Body);
                                                emailList.Add(mailItem);
                                                //make email read so that we can avoid infinite loops of emails
                                                //being sent
                                                mailItem.UnRead = false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        catch (System.Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outlookApp);
                return (bodyList.ToArray(), emailList.ToArray());
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
            return (null, null);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            (string[] bodyArray, olook.MailItem[] emails) = ReadMail();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

My Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll is selected. I am using file version 14.0.  I am up-to-date on my Outlook application on my virtual machine. I have no window updates. I have restarted my virtual machine. I don't understand why it was working, and now it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The error `80080005` "Server execution failed" (which is `CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE`) most likely means your app and Outlook are running in different security contexts and the COM system is refusing to marshal the calls.

Make sure either both apps run with elevated privileges (Run as Administrator) or neither one does.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond! I am an admin of both Visual Studios and Outlook

Comment: Do you mean you run both from a context menu by clicking 'Run As Administrator"?